# Problem with Multi-Threading/Multi-Processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a ZMQ feed and a scheduler from package Schedule that I am trying to call in different while loops.

The zmq feed will run for 3 hours then my scheduler from package Schedule will run my processing function which stops the ZMQ process cleanly (currently using multiprocessing) do the actual processing on the data then restart the process at the end of the function.

The reason im doing this currently is because I believe there is an issue with multi threading continuously appending zmq feed data to the dataframe while the actually data processing is happening.

So that leads me to using multi processing. I have tried just creating processes out of the functions then starting them and calling join

```
process = Process(target = run, args = ('bob',))
process1 = Process(target = schedule1, args = 'bob',)
process.start()
process1.start()
process.join()
process1.join()
```

and

```
with Pool(2) as p:
    p.map(process, "1")
    p.map(process1, "1")
```

run and schedule 1 are my functions

```
with Pool(2) as p:
        p.map(schedule1, "1")
        p.map(run, "1")
```

Just tried this above and now its just stuck not printing anything from my while loops telling me its active. So not sure whats goin on here

and

```
pool = Pool()
result1 = pool.apply_async(schedule, '1')
result2 = pool.apply_async(run, '1')
```

They all don't work and do not start any of my two while loops. While multithreading could at least do that. The reason I moved to multiprocessing was due to the fact that I can stop and start processing at will cleanly and easily with .terminate() then .join(), then restart it with .start() .join()

Any help would be useful or any pointers to where I'm going wrong.

The arguments in all the functions are dummy arguments built in for the .map because you need to pass arguments.

Comment: Why are we starting and stopping Zero MQ?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish  Because the ZMQ feed is taking the string, converting to a pd.series then appending to a empty dataframe. I believe one of my issues is the fact that ZMQ is still appending to the dataframe when I am processing the data creating an issue. I'm not sure how it works with ZMQ appending. It seems only after I stop it do I get access to the dataframe variable to run the processing on. It could be either or.

Comment: I believe I know this because when I run the processing function it throws key errors like it doesnt have any data to work on.